# Nativescript Back Button not redirecting to the correct page

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to create an Angular 2 component for Android that displays the content of a specific **path**. For this I created the following app-routing.module:

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'folder-content/:path', component: FolderContentComponent },

    ])
  ],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

For completeness, here is the xml for folder-content.xml

```
<StackLayout>
    <GridLayout row="auto, *" row="2">
        <ListView [items]="getContent(currentPath)">
            <template let-item="item">
                <GridLayout columns="auto, *"   [nsRouterLink]="['/folder-content', item.path]">
                    <GridLayout columns="auto" rows="auto" cssClass="favorite-wrap">
                        <Image id="imgFav" [src]="item.isFile() ? 'res://ic_add_to_fav_1': 'res://folder'" stretch = "none" cssClass="icon-image"></Image>
                    </GridLayout>
                    <StackLayout col="1">
                        <Label [text]="item.name" cssClass="info-bigger"></Label>
                        <Label [text]="item.path" cssClass="info-orange"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
            </template>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Each time I tap on a list item, I want to navigate to the same page, but with a different parameter (This works as expected).

The problem is when I try to navigate back (using the physical back button) I get redirected to the HomeComponent instead of FolderContentComponent.

I tried printing the router events to get more information using the following snippet:

```
 router.events.forEach((event) => {
     console.log(event);
    });
```

*I get the following when navigating from  **the default path** to **folder-content +'/'** as a parameter:*

```
JS: NavigationStart(id: 19, url: '/folder-content/%2F')
JS: RoutesRecognized(id: 19, url: '/folder-content/%2F', urlAfterRedirects: '/folder-content/%2F', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'folder-content/%2F', path:'folder-content/:path') } )
JS: NavigationEnd(id: 19, url: '/folder-content/%2F', urlAfterRedirects: '/folder-content/%2F')
```

*I get the following when navigating from  **folder-content +'/'** to **folder-content +'/sdcard':***

```
JS: NavigationStart(id: 20, url: '/folder-content/%2Fsdcard')
JS: RoutesRecognized(id: 20, url: '/folder-content/%2Fsdcard', urlAfterRedirects: '/folder-content/%2Fsdcard', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'folder-content/%2Fsdcard', path:'folder-content/:path') } )
JS: NavigationEnd(id: 20, url: '/folder-content/%2Fsdcard', urlAfterRedirects: '/folder-content/%2Fsdcard')
```

*However, when pressing the back button I would expect to navigate from f**older-content +'/sdcard'** to **folder-content + '/'** but in stead I get redirected to '' (HomeComponent)*

```
JS: NavigationStart(id: 21, url: '/')
JS: RoutesRecognized(id: 21, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
JS: NavigationEnd(id: 21, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
```

*It's important to mention that I am using **page-router-outlet** and not the standard Angular router.*

*TNS version: 2.5.1*, 
*Angular version: 2.4.3*, 
*Android platform  6.0.1*

Comment: How many component do you have? Only Home,folderContent?

Comment: I have a sidebar component, about and contact component, and the app component. Other than the sidebar, all of them are just dummy pages with no real functionality

Comment: did u override the android back button event?

Comment: No, because, according to the docs, the router should support that out of the box: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html#navigation-options

Comment: @RaduCojocari Based on Your Implementation. In my case I've overrided all android back events based on my requirements

Comment: @RaduCojocari did you ever solve this? I have this problem as well...

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. This is partially the reason why I gave up on the framework. (for now at least)

Answer (score 1):

Try to this for back button.

Add this code in your project **app.component.ts** :-

```
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";

clickCount: number = 0;

constructor() {
 if (application.android) {            
  application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: any) => {
            if (this._routerExtensions.router.url == '/home') {
                data.cancel = (this.clickCount++ > 0) ? false : true;
                if (data.cancel) Toast.makeText("Press again to exit", "long").show();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.tries = 0;
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

> One page to another page redirection code

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

constructor(private zone: NgZone,
    private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions){ }

gotoFolderContentPage() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this._routerExtensions.navigate(["folder-content",1], {
                clearHistory: (isIOS) ? true : false,
            });
        });
    }, 500);
}
```